# Failure to startx on Ubuntu 14.04 after security update - missing libXfont.so.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, upgrade, startx

I had Ubuntu 14.04 running perfectly on my system and then it underwent a recommended security update. I let it update while I was at work and when I returned I found a black screen stating, "No init found" and "mount: mounting /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root on /root failed: Invalid argument". I followed some guides and ran the following commands:

```
ls /dev/sd*
sudo apt-get install lvm2
sudo pvscan
sudo vgscan
sudo vgchange -a y ubuntu-vg
sudo fsck /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
```

After running those commands and rebooting, my Linux system was back up and running again; however, not quite like it was before. It starts up into command line mode (without GUI) and asks for my username and password. When I log in and try "startx" I get the following:

```
user@home-pc:~$ startx
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/user/.Xauthority
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/user/.Xauthority

/usr/bin/X: error while loading shared libraries: libXfont.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/user/.Xauthority
user@home-pc:~$
```

I get the same message when I try "sudo startx". I believe this error is due to the symbolic link that is used to identify the "libXfont.so.1" file, but I don't know how to fix this problem. I already tried running "sudo apt-get update && sudo-apt-get dist-upgrade" in hopes that this would fix or finish the upgrade and/or installing of the security update, but this didn't fix the problem. Does anyone have any idea on what is going on or how I can fix this?

Comment: Which guides did you follow?

Comment: I didn't follow any actual guides. The system had a dialog box that said there was about 62 MB of security related updates that were available and after the update it rendered my system unusable. I've scoured the internet for problems related to "libXfont.so.1" and tried everything I could but nothing seems to fix this problem.

Comment: This is common; You should re-intsall your Xorg and video driver and reboot after that

Comment: To re-install xorg, I would run "sudo apt-get remove xorg && sudo apt-get install xorg", but what do I do to re-install the video card? I was using the proprietary driver from nvidia for one of the gtx series video cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tip: try to `locate libXfont.so.1` or `libXfont.so`. If it's located make a symlink to it:

```
ln -s `locate libXfont.so.1 | line` /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

As `mikeserv` [suggested below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137341/failure-to-startx-on-ubuntu-14-04-after-security-update-missing-libxfont-so-1/137359?noredirect=1#comment219277_137359), quick and dirty fix is to find `libXfont.so.N` and make symlink `libXfont.so.1 >> libXfont.so.N`.

You can also check if `X` requires some other shared libraries by issuing `ldd /usr/bin/X`.

> #### To summarize chat discussion: issue was fixed by:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge libxfont1
> sudo apt-get install libxfont1 xorg
> sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
> reboot
> ```

Comment: Hey - it's that ninja turtle guy. You beat me to it. It might also be a `.2` now or something, by the way.

Comment: My cousin's name is Raphael and we know some karate =P. `.1` is the suffix that OP provided.

Comment: I suspected as much, so I'll tread carefully. But I meant maybe it can't find the `.1` lib because some unmanaged package depends on the `.1` version but his recent update could have upgraded it and incremented the version number. That's only speculation, but I often find a quick and dirty fix in those situations is to symlink `old.1 -->> new.2`.

Comment: I can't find libXfont.so.1 on my system. ldd /usr/bin/X shows: linux-vdso.so.1 =>, libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6, and /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Comment: @user2554129 Do you have package `libxfont1` installed?

Comment: Yes. I tried "sudo apt-get install libxfont1" and it said it was already installed. Then I tried "sudo apt-get upgrade libxfont1" and it upgraded but I'm still getting the same error, "error while loading shared libraries: libXfont.so.1"

Comment: @user2554129 try to reinstall that package. Sometimes they are just marked as installed.

Comment: I think we may be onto something, because I'm getting different messages when trying to use startx (which is refreshing). But did I mess up by choosing to use "sudo apt-get remove --purge libxfont1"? Because that removed a lot of stuff and now I can't seem to find the opposite of that command to re-install it all back.

Comment: Just tried, "sudo apt-get install libxfont1 && sudo apt-get install xorg" and then tried startx. I'm still getting a timeout in locking authority file, but now it says "Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found(EE). It's still refreshing to see something other than a complaint about libXfont! :-P

Comment: @user2554129 Uh-oh. Reinstallation should be done by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall`. Now you should install `xserver-xorg` and `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15142/discussion-between-danatela-and-user2554129).

Comment: Additional recommendations from Danatela: sudo apt-get install --reinstall. Now you should install xserver-xorg and ubuntu-desktop. After running "sudo apt-get remove --purge libxfont1", and then "sudo apt-get install libxfont1 && sudo apt-get install xorg" I got the fatal error, but then I rebooted the machine and now it is finally able to startx and I'm on the lightdm login screen. I still had problems getting to my desktop so I deleted the .Xauthority file and restarted. Now things are working like normal! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf ~/.Xauthority
```

I think it should be recreated correctly after reboot/login; might be a good idea to try that **first** w/out reinstalling `xorg` and/or `libXfont1`.  If error persists, *then* try reinstalling `libXfont1`.